# Dart/Flutter connecting to a SSL Websocket

Tags: flutter, ssl, websocket, flutter-web

I have a backend websocket server written in Python. I'm using the [websockets](https://websockets.readthedocs.io/en/stable/intro.html#secure-example) package and implementing a secured connection:

```py
context = ssl.create_default_context()
server_corroutine = websockets.serve(self._ui_requests, "localhost", 8765, ssl=context)
```

On the front end I have a Flutter Web application. I think this complicates things a bit since I cannot use the dart:io package. I'm using a generic implementation package [web_socket_channel](https://pub.dev/packages/web_socket_channel)

```dart
_socket = WebSocketChannel.connect(Uri.parse('wss://localhost:8765'));
```

The answers that I found point to adding

```dart
import 'package:universal_io/io.dart'; //using universal implementation since I'm on web

class MyHttpOverrides extends HttpOverrides{
  @override
  HttpClient createHttpClient(SecurityContext? context){
    return super.createHttpClient(context)
      ..badCertificateCallback = (X509Certificate cert, String host, int port)=> true;
  }
}

void main() {
  HttpOverrides.global = new MyHttpOverrides();
```

But this doesn't seem to work... I've been searching for hours and I haven't got any progress.

Can anyone please help me?